# Union between two jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

This is my case:

```
var elems = form.find(':input');
var clEditors = form.find('.cleditor').parent();

elems.css('border', '2px');
clEditors.css('border', '2px');
```

Is there anyway I could prevent the duplication and do something like this:

```
var elems = form.find(':input').union(form.find('.cleditor').parent());
elems.css('border', '2px');
```

I tried using a multi selector with the `:parent` selector and it didn't work:

```
var elems = form.find(':input, .cleditor:parent');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `add()` method to join two jQuery objects:

```
var $elems = form.find(':input').add(form.find('.cleditor').parent());
$elems.css('border', '2px');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't familiar with the add method. Thank you!! I will accept ASAP.